# Write base64 string as pdf to phone storage using Phonegap

Tags: javascript, pdf, cordova

I have requirement to write pdf to phone storage using **Phonegap**, but **phonegap** only supports text writting in file. I have `base64` string which contains pdf doc, and I want to save it to **Phonestorage**. I have tried to convert `base64` to `utf-8` using atob function and then write it to pdf, but it is not also working.

Is there something else that I should try? or is there any plugin available?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a normal pdf writer method in java. For the same iText or any other pdf writers can be used. Expose a public method in this writer class as a [Javascript Interface.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html) 
Eg :

```
Class PdfWriter{

@JavascriptInterface
    public void writeToPdf(String dataToBeWritten) {
        writeToFile(dataToBeWritten);
    }
}
```

[Register this as a JavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) with the webview.

Once the webview is loaded, you should be able to call:

```
window.PdfWriter.writeToPdf("data_to_be_written")
```

Comment: I prefer to write it using Java script only, because I am creating hybrid application

Comment: Basically you are creating a Cordova Plugin manually with the above approach. From your question it seems you are fine with using a Plugin. You can also try the approach mentioned in [this](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2014/01/08/generating-pdf-inside-of-phonegap-apps/) post

Answer (score 0):

The base64 PDF data needs to be converted to a fileblob.

You can then save that fileblob as a PDF file using the cordova-file plugin.

[Convert base64 string as pdf in phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273685/convert-base64-string-as-pdf-in-phonegap)

Comment: That's correct, but Blob may not be supported by all the Rendering Engines.

Comment: The answer in the linked post has been updated. If blob is not supported by the render engine it falls back to the older blobbuilder.